# Performing LEFT OUTER minus INNER JOIN in Tableau

Tags: join, datasource, tableau-api

I've a requirement where I need to JOIN two data sources in Tableau such that 
it's LEFT OUTER JOIN minus INNER JOIN.

How to perform this in Tableau at the data source? as Tableau only supports inner, left, right and full outer joins.

Comment: what type of datasources are you dealing with?

Comment: can show sample data with expected results on how exactly you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Tableau Desktop, one option is to define a datasource filter using the join key of the second data source.

1. Create a left join from source1 to source2
2. Create a new datasource filter for source2.join_key using, go to "Condition" tab, choose "By formula" option and use "ISNULL([source2.join_key])"